# Validation for disable button webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've written some code using C# and WebDriver and I'm stuck dealing with a disabled `IWebElement`. After clicking "Lock", I want to validate that the Edit button is disabled. I'm currently getting an error

> Failed to lock a version, error: There is no disabled button Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code is below.

```
public bool elementDisplayed()
{
    try
    {
        if (Continue.Enabled == true)
            Console.WriteLine("There is a disable button");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("There is no disabled button " + ex.Message);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have HTML of the Continue button:

< a class="btn btn-amber btn-open btn-md ng-scope" href="#" ng-if="$ctrl.isCurrentProject" ng-click="$ctrl.continue()" ng-class="{ 'disabled': $ctrl.project.isLocked }" translate="PROJECT_CARD.CONTINUE" style="" > Continue

Continue button in Webdriver:

var Continue = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@translate='PROJECT_CARD.CO‌​NTINUE']"))

Comment: Please provide a link to the page and/or post the relevant HTML. My guess is that the Continue button isn't actually an INPUT element. `Enabled` only works on INPUT elements. You'll have to detect whether the button is "disabled" another way like CSS style applied, etc.

Comment: What locator are you using for `Continue`?

Comment: Please respond to my first comment also.

Comment: This webpage is only internal web system. We use it for HR by Intranet. When I get a new record, I can click Lock then Continue button should be disable.    <a class="btn btn-amber btn-open btn-md ng-scope" href="#" ng-if="$ctrl.isCurrentProject" ng-click="$ctrl.continue()" ng-class="{ 'disabled': $ctrl.project.isLocked }" translate="PROJECT_CARD.CONTINUE" style="">Continue</a>

Comment: Please edit your post and move the HTML for the buttons into your question so it's more easily found.